# Why does my method sometimes print multiple lines?

Tags: java, random, systemtime

So I Have this method

```
public int sumMathRandomAndSystemTime(){

    n = 1 + ((int) (Math.random() * 10)+ 
            (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() % 10));

    if(n > 10){
        sumMathRandomAndSystemTime();
    }
    System.out.println(n);
    return n;

}
```

All I want is to print one random number (n) between 1 and 10 once. But for some reason, when I call the method it does print a random number, but some times only once, other times it prints the number like 10 times, 5 times, etc. Why is this happening?

Here's an example of my output

```
10
10
10
10
10
```

Comment: Because it's recursive.

Comment: What's the point of this method?

Comment: ok, but how do i get rid of the multiple lines of print? Any suggestions?

Comment: if you are trying to print when n is bigger than 10. wrap you print method call with else block

Comment: Remove the recursive call. It doesn't even do anything (other than printing)

Comment: I just want to print a random number, which I get from the sum of a Math.Random number and another random number using System time, where the sum has to be between 1 and 10

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Put the word “return” before sumMathRandomAndSystemTime();

Answer (score 3):

IF the original random number is larger then 10, your code will print multiple lines: one for each recursive call.

You can change your code as following to solve this problem:

```
public int sumMathRandomAndSystemTime(){

    int n = getRandomNumber();
    System.out.println(n);
    return n;

}

public int getRandomNumber() {
    int n = 1 + ((int) (Math.random() * 10)+
            (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() % 10));

    if(n > 10){
        n = getRandomNumber();
    }
    return n;
}
```

And in general a much simpler code would be:

```
public int sumMathRandomAndSystemTime(){
    Random random = new Random();
    int n = random.nextInt(10);
    System.out.println(n);
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to print one random number between 1 and 10, try something like this...

```
        int n;
        do
        {
          n = 1 + ((int) (Math.random() * 10) + (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() % 10));
        } while(n > 10);

        return n;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add return statement after sumMathRandomAndSystemTime(); call.

```
public static int sumMathRandomAndSystemTime(){
    n = 1 + ((int) (Math.random() * 10)+ 
            (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() % 10));
    if(n > 10){
        sumMathRandomAndSystemTime();
        return n;
    }
    System.out.println(n);
    return n;
}
```

May be this picture can clear the flow.

[image]